# (gcloud.beta.compute.scp) Could not add SSH key to instance metadata permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scp, google-cloud-iam

I'd like to get automated deployments going for a VM that I have running in Google Cloud and as part of that, I'm trying to use a service account to SCP my files up to a VM in GCP, but unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out what the correct permissions should be.

After scouring the documentation, I have a service account with these permissions:

- compute.instances.get
- compute.instances.setMetadata
- compute.projects.get
- compute.projects.setCommonInstanceMetadata

but when I run the below commands, I get the below output:

```
+ ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=./service-account.json
Activated service account credentials for: [scp-test@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
+ ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud beta compute scp hello.txt scp-test:c:/hello.txt --quiet --project=my-project --ssh-key-file=./.ssh/key --zone=us-east4-c
WARNING: The public SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: The private SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.
WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed to generate a key.
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /Users/mac-user/Downloads/scp-test/.ssh/key.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/mac-user/Downloads/scp-test/.ssh/key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
{OMMITED}
The key's randomart image is:
{OMMITED}
External IP address was not found; defaulting to using IAP tunneling.
Updating project ssh metadata...failed.
Updating instance ssh metadata...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.scp) Could not add SSH key to instance metadata:
 - The user does not have access to service account '{OMMITED}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com'.  User: 'scp-test@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.  Ask a project owner to grant you the iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account
```

granting my scp-test user the iam.serviceAccountUser role works, but this seems to be bad practice since it then makes my scp-test user able to impersonate the default account ('{OMMITED}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com'.), which then seems to give it full access to everything.

How do I grant it only the permissions that it needs for SCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use SSH/SCP you need instance admin rights to Compute Engine.

Service account means the service account IAM member that gcloud is configured to use: `scp-test@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

You need to give the service account this role:

```
roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1
```

Since your compute instance is also configured to use a service account, you also need this role for your service account:

```
roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
```

Comment: Okay, but doesn't that give my service account access to do everything the default service account can do? I was under the impression that that might be bad practice? My goal was to have a service account that I used for deployments where I could call gcloud scp and have it push my code out, preferably without managing the private key myself. Also, thanks for your time.

Comment: To use the SSH/SCP features you need to be an admin. The default compute engine service account is a Project Editor which has even more permissions. However, you are confusing who and where permissions are applied. You need to assign permissions to the CLI service account and not to the compute engine instance.

Comment: The CLI gets you into the instance, from there the compute engine service account defines what you can do once you are inside. So Yes, you are indirectly allowing the user permissions in the instance to do anything that the compute engine service account allows. If you do not want that, then you cannot give the CLI permission to do so. In your case, best practice is to restrict the compute engine service account to minimum permissions necessary.